# ExpressJS Redirect Method

Tags: node.js, express

If I use the `res.redirect( url )` will the redirection method also append the previous parameters to where it will be redirected?

It means if I passed/send request with a json parameters using POST method then I redirect the request to another server, will that other server (where it is redirected) receives the json parameters?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's a plain and simple HTTP Redirect header, most browsers will just "jump" to the destination URL when receiving such a header.

If you're posting programmatically, then how to react to the HTTP Redirect header is all up to you. You can send the original data to the redirect destination if you want.

See also:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection